# Why are USB/DVI KVM switches so much more expensive than USB/DSUB models?

Tags: keyboard-video-mouse

Newegg lists nine 4 computer USB/DSUB switches for between $40 and $100; but the cheapest USB/DVI model is almost $200.

Is DVI that much inherently harder to switch; or has the inventory of dsub capable models had their price slashed in order to clear the obsolete inventory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, DSUB is pretty much a unidirectional port.  The computer (or whatever) sprays bits at the monitor, and hopefully they all get there.  That makes switching pretty easy.  DVI, on the other hand, is bidirectional, and has some protocol to it.  A switch thus needs to correctly implement that protocol, and do all the stuff that requires.

So, DVI is probably harder :)

Comment: The same is true in comparing PS2 to USB; but there's very little price difference between PS2/DSUB ans USB/DSUB any longer.

Comment: While the same is true from point of theory, the USB interface is much simpler than DVI.

Comment: Why the hate, SF?

Comment: Ok, "Why the hate, single SF user?" would be more accurate :)

Answer (score 1):

DVI has a throughput of about 5Gb/s while VGA is 172mHz.  Anytime you're looking at electronic components, the one with the higher clock frequency is going to be more expensive.  This has to do with having a higher density and tighter manufacturing tolerances of the components.

Comment: While I agree with your point, the mixing of units there is kind of rough.